# Allow admins to edit users details including password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-engines

I'm building an engine for administration, so I need to have some way to change the user details, including passwords.

Currently my form is complaining about the empty password, when I change other fields. I want to change them without filling the password fields.

One solution would be to "manually" check the parameters and remove the passwords parameters if they are empty, but this looks hackish.

To allow to treat users like resources, so I can execute the CRUD operations, I add it to the `routes.rb`:

```
Admin::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
require_dependency "admin/application_controller"

module Admin
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /users
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    # GET /users/1
    def show
    end

    # GET /users/new
    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    # GET /users/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /users
    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
        redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /users/1
    def update
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if(@user == current_user and @user.admin_locked)
          redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated, but you locked yourself.'
        else
          redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
        end
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end

    # DELETE /users/1
    def destroy
      @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.'
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :role, :password, :password_confirmation, :reset_password_token, :admin_locked)
    end
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>

<section>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, required: true%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :role %><br>
    <%= f.select :role, User.roles.keys.to_a.map {|role| [role.humanize, role]} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password, "New password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :admin_locked,  'Locked'%><br>
    <%= f.check_box :admin_locked %>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**user.rb**

```
module Admin
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :password, length: { in: 6..128 }, on: :update, allow_blank: true
  end
end
```

**logs:**

```
Started PATCH "/admin/users/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-23 16:16:15 +0000
Processing by Admin::UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OZC69AMbTAfp361HKHTYHUKnEvAI+2zf7z0k08S4a/mxHOV+IZ0r3uFxrSX2E6Euj10ZlXLK1BzKB8dsGIAEnA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"ze@ze.com", "role"=>"admin", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin_locked"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered admin/app/views/admin/users/_form.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered admin/app/views/admin/users/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin/application (5.9ms)
  Rendered admin/app/views/layouts/admin/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered admin/app/views/layouts/admin/_navigation.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered admin/app/views/layouts/admin/_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 21.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

Versions: Rails 4.2, devise 3.4.1

**NOTE for close reviews:** this is not a typical Rails app, it's happening in a Rails Engine. If you vote to close please understand the difference.

Comment: @smathy Not a duplicate, because even if I add the updated validation constraints allowing blanks, it will fail

Comment: How so? Are you not providing a blank password when you're updating from the admin form?

Comment: @smathy I just want to change other field(s) leaving the password as is, so it will be blank. I've updated the answer to reflect the goal more clearly I hope.

Comment: Either way I'm not sure why one of the answers in the other thread don't work for you, either the `allow_blank: true` or the `update_without_password`